# Converting $1B into number

Tags: python, pandas

I retrieve a csv file from nasdaq website with a few columns (Ticker, MarketCap...). I use read_csv from pandas to get a dataframe. My problem is that I can't convert the format of the MarketCap column into a number.
This is how the MarketCap column looks like:

```
MarketCap
$5.54B
$526.85M
$28.41M
nan
nan
```

Ideally I would want to drop the $ sign and convert B into 1'000'000'000 and M into 1'000'000
The replace/to_replace functions in pandas don't seem to work here.
I would like to update my dataframe as follow:

```
MarketCap
5'540'000'000'000
526'850'000'000
28'410'000'000
nan
nan
```

(I used ' as thousand separator just for clarity). I don't care about the nan values, so this can't be dropped/ignored for now.

I tried to use the replace method from pandas as follow:

```
df['MarketCap].replace(to_replace= ['B', 'M'], values= ['*1000000000', '*1000000'], inplace=True)
```

unfortunately since the column is of string format the above doesn't apply the multiplication.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), then multiple first column converted to floats and second mapped by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = df['MarketCap'].str.strip('$').str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+)([BM]+)')
df['MarketCap'] = df1[0].astype(float) * df1[1].map({'B': 1000000000, 'M':1000000})

print (df)
      MarketCap
0  5.540000e+09
1  5.268500e+08
2  2.841000e+07
3           NaN
4           NaN
```